# Maximum/Minimum of a quadratic form on the unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Prove that, the maximum/minimum of the quadratic form
$$
f(x, y, z)=A x^{2}+B y^{2}+C z^{2}+2 D y z+2 E z x+2 F x y
$$
on the unit sphere surface
$$
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1
$$
is exactly the corresponding max/min eigenvalue of the matrix
$$
\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
A & F & E \\
F & B & D \\
E & D & C
\end{array}\right)
$$

I don't even know where to start. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key fact is that every real symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalisable, i.e. we can express $\Phi$ as $Q\Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries the eigenvalues of $\Phi$. The proof of this fact can be found in most introductory texts on linear algebra.

Since $Q$ is orthogonal, $(x,y,z)\mapsto(u,v,w):=(x,y,z)Q$ is a bijective mapping on the unit sphere. Hence
$$
\max_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}f(x,y,z)
=\max_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}\pmatrix{x&y&z}\Phi\pmatrix{x\\ y\\ z}
=\max_{u^2+v^2+w^2=1}\pmatrix{u&v&w}\Lambda\pmatrix{u\\ v\\ w}
$$
and the rest should be straightforward.